# Die Relationen, welche zwischen den elementaren symmetrischen Functionen bestehen - Translation?

Tags: reference-request, commutative-algebra, symmetric-polynomials, translation-request, mathematical-german

I am trying to find a translation of [this paper](https://doi.org/10.1007/BF01212695) either in English or French (preferably English).

I am not very optimistic, but i thought of asking in case somebody is more resourceful :)

Comment: The bibliographic information is, F. Junker, Die Relationen, welche zwischen den elementaren symmetrischen Functionen bestehen, Mathematische Annalen 1891, Volume 38, Issue 1, pp 91-114.

Comment: Manos, did I sacrifice the right tag?

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo: Hi Rodrigo, I am not sure I understand your question.

Comment: Manos, I sacrificed tag [tag:symmetric-groups] to introduce tag [tag:mathematical-german]. Not sure it was a wise decision, so I asked you.

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo I see. I am not sure either. It looks ok though.